# Mystery persistent /8 on routing table

Tags: iproute2, static-routes

I have the below route listed, that is persistent over restarts.

```
"route -n"
69.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 eth0
```

and

```
"ip route"
69.0.0.0/8 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 69.1XX.XXX.X7 metric 100
```

While "grep -r "69.0.0.0" /etc" returns nothing.
OS is CENTOS7.

What other locations/configuration files regularly hold static routes?   Or how can I determine what config files are being used to build my route table.

Or is there some other gotcha with regards to general ip management?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html

Comment: If your interface IP is 69.1xx.xxx.x7/8 then you will have a route to 69.0.0.0/8, which is why you don't find 69.0.0.0 in /etc

Comment: Interface on this server is 69.1xx.xxx.x7/27, and I understand that there should be a /8 in the mix, but why is it getting added to the table via 0.0.0.0?